# jQuery validate error "jquery.format is not a function" after plugin update

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

For years I was jQuery.validate using version 1.9.0 successfully
Now, with v 1.19.2 I get "jquery.format is not a function".
In my head section:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.19.2/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.19.2/additional-methods.min.js" ></script>
```

html form input

```
<div class="divTableCell L3"><input name="email" type="text" class="required" id="email" /></div>
```

At bottom:

```
<script>
    formVerif();
</script>
```

This is a part of the function used:

```
function formVerif(){   
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#formulario").validate({
          errorClass: 'rojo' ,
          messages: {
               nombre: {
                 required: "<br />Falta ingresar un nombre.",
                 minlength: jQuery.format("<br />Ingresa al menos {0} caracteres"),
                 maxlength: jQuery.format("<br />Ingresa como máximo {0} caracteres"),
                 alphanumeric: "<br />Ingresa solo letras y espacios"
                 },
               apellido: {
               ...
               ...
```

If I go back to V 1.9.0 no errors are displayed:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="JS/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="JS/additional-methods.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: There is no such thing as `jQuery.format` - it should be `jQuery.validator.format`.  Your example code is also incomplete. You only show us the HTML for the field with `name="email"` and then show the `.validate()` method with completely different fields.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code...

```
minlength: jQuery.format("<br />Ingresa al menos {0} caracteres"),
```

There is no such thing as `jQuery.format`, so just remove and use this...

```
minlength: "<br />Ingresa al menos {0} caracteres",
```

It still works the same...

**DEMO**:  [jsfiddle.net/w09fqj3n/](https://jsfiddle.net/w09fqj3n/)

[Reviewing the documentation](https://jqueryvalidation.org/jQuery.validator.format/), `jQuery.format` is supposed to be `jQuery.validator.format`, but it's apparently optional.

---

Also, putting the DOM ready event handler inside a function that you call at the bottom of the page does not make sense...

```
function formVerif(){   
    $(document).ready(function(){ ....
```

The main purpose of [the ready event handler](https://api.jquery.com/ready/) is to *"Specify a function to execute when the DOM is fully loaded."*  Calling it from a function at the bottom of the page renders its usage completely pointless.  Just put the ready handler at the bottom if you wish to defer loading scripts until the end.

Answer (score 0):

```
 jQuery.validator.addMethod("extension", function(value, element, param) {
                            param = typeof param === "string" ? param.replace(/,/g, '|') : "png|jpe?g|gif";
                            return this.optional(element) || value.match(new RegExp(".(" + param + ")$", "i"));
                        },  jQuery.format("Please enter a value with a valid extension."));
```

remove `jQuery.format()`